# XCode 7 debug area toolbar diffrence

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

In XCode 6 Debug Area:

`Debug area | break point | Pause | step over | step into | step out |`

[image]

In XCode 7  (`Version 7.0 beta (7A120f)`):

`Debug area | break point |`

[image]

How i can get other debug option in XCode7 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to debug! As soon as you are actually running some code, those buttons will appear.

Code not running:

[image]

Code running:

[image]

It's nice, because it gives you some extra visual indication of when your code *is* running.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following Scheme setting lead to the same missing debugging buttons even though the app is running (device or simulator):

[image: Scheme setting removing the possibility to debug]